# Could not read "priv/post": no such file or directory

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, exrm

I've been trying to build an blog using Phoenix, and deploy it with exrm. Everything works error-free in development, but the exrm release gives me errors when I try to open it in a console. I've been following this [tutorial](http://www.sebastianseilund.com/static-markdown-blog-posts-with-elixir-phoenix).

This is the error message I get in iex:

```
[info] Application blog exited: Blog.start(:normal, []) returned an error: shutdown: failed to start child: Blog.Repo
    ** (EXIT) an exception was raised:
        ** (File.Error) could not list directory "priv/posts": no such file or directory
            (elixir) lib/file.ex:1174: File.ls!/1
            (blog) lib/blog/crawler.ex:3: Blog.Crawler.crawl/0
            (elixir) lib/agent/server.ex:8: Agent.Server.init/1
            (stdlib) gen_server.erl:328: :gen_server.init_it/6
            (stdlib) proc_lib.erl:247: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
```

Just to be clear the directory "priv/posts" does exist in my project. And `mix phoenix.server` does recognize it. It's only showing the error in the exrm release.

Comment: the error says failed to start child Blog.Repo.Did you put it in your supervisor?

Comment: Turns out it's a problem with how the directory was specified in the function. It should have been `Application.app_dir("priv/posts")` instead of just `"priv/posts"`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem can be solved by replacing "priv/posts"  with Application.app_path(app_name, "priv/posts").